# redis port and host undefined even though env are set

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, redis

I am using the `redis` npm package and whenever I try to connect to it, it's saying the `host` and `port` are undefined. I print out my `process.env` object and I can see that the `host` and `port` have values set. It's only when I pass the values into my constructor for my `Redis` model class, that it becomes undefined. Any ideas?

`index.js`

```
require('dotenv').config()


function startRedis() {
    const redisInstance = new Redis(
        process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        process.env.REDIS_PORT
    );
    
    redisInstance.init();
}



class Redis {
        constructor(redishost, redisport) {
            this.redishost = redishost;
            this.redisport = redisport;
        }
    
        async init() {
            try {
                this.redisClient = redis.createClient({
                    port: this.redisport, 
                    host: this.redishost
                });
                
            console.log("port: ", this.port)
            console.log("host: ", this.host)
    
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(`Error creating client due to: ${error}`)
            }
}
```

`.env`

```
REDIS_HOST="value here"
REDIS_PORT="port value here"
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

`Update 1`: Added my package.json

Comment: who did you reading your .env like using `dotenv` library ? did `process.env.REDIS_HOST` having value did you try to log it ?

Comment: yeah i am using the dotenv package. @HellCatVN

Comment: Yes when I log there are values. When the constructor tries to create then the values are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see here if `process.env.REDIS_HOST` having value.

You have new on wrong class name

Your start function should be like

```js
function startRedis() {
    const redisInstance = new Redis(
        process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        process.env.REDIS_PORT
    );
    
    redisInstance.init();
}
```

And you are console.log wrong value

```js
class Redis {
        constructor(redishost, redisport) {
            this.redishost = redishost;
            this.redisport = redisport;
        }
    
        async init() {
            try {
                this.redisClient = redis.createClient({
                    port: this.redisport, 
                    host: this.redishost
                });
                
            console.log("port: ", this.redisport)
            console.log("host: ", this.redishost)
    
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(`Error creating client due to: ${error}`)
            }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to rename the class name when I updated the post. The issue still occurs.

Comment: Try to log before new Redis and tell me if it still undefined , show more code at import where you try to using `dotenv` to reading env file

Comment: I logged before new Redis and it has values. When it goes into the `Redis` class, before the constructor call, it has values. Only when the constructor get's called, the values are undefined.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand

Comment: when you say declare what are you referring to? Can you update your code and show me?

Comment: Thanks. Try to code more careful ^^. Too much missing in your code